# JSP not re-instantiating

Tags: java, arrays, jsp

This is an online library website I am trying to make. For advanced search which can take multiple inputs, I start of with an array of all publications then I remove items which don't match the user input. This works fine for the first time, where the array gets shortened to just the correct array. So if someone typed "programming" all of the publications which have programming in their title will be shown. Now, if the user clicks on the "Advance Search" button again on the NavBar (as shown in welcome.jsp) and inputs say "UML" my code will perform a search for UML on the shortened array which contains results for only "programming". I have put a print statement above

`SearchResult sr = new SearchResult();
sr.searchContains = publications;`

(In control servlet) and it prints for both inputs UML and programming, but it seems to either not create a new array with all publications?

searchResult.jsp:

`<c:forEach var="current" items="${sr.searchContains}">
    Title: ${current.title}
</c:forEach>`

ControllerServlet.java:

```
 if (action.equals("advSearch")) {
             SearchResult sr = new SearchResult();
             sr.searchContains = publications;

             nextPage = "searchResult.jsp";

             String titleString = request.getParameter("titleString");

             if (!titleString.equals("")){
                 ArrayList<Publication> toRemove = new ArrayList<Publication>();
                 for (Publication p : sr.searchContains){
                     if (!p.title.contains(titleString)){
                         toRemove.add(p);
                     } 
                 } 
                 sr.searchContains.removeAll(toRemove);

             }
 request.getSession().setAttribute("sr", sr);
             RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/"+searchResult.jsp);
             rd.forward(request, response);
```

welcome.jsp:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="advancedSearch.jsp">Advance Search <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        </ul>
```

advancedSearch.jsp:

```
<form action="controller" method="POST">
  <div class="form-group">
     <label for="title">Title:</label>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" name="titleString">
     <input type="hidden" name="action" value="advSearch" />
  </div>
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Advanced Search</button>
</form>
```

SearchResult.jsp:

```
public class SearchResult {
    public ArrayList<Publication> searchContains = new ArrayList<Publication>();

    public ArrayList<Publication> getSearchContains (){
        return this.searchContains;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, the problem was in controlservlet

```
SearchResult sr = new SearchResult();
sr.searchContains = publications;
```

This means sr.searchContains is the same reference as publications, the main array.